# Why does presigned post require s3:PutObjectAcl permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I thought it'd only need the `s3:PutObject` permission since the object hasn't been created yet.

I did something like:

```
post = bucket.presigned_post({
  key: "/uploads/${filename}",
  acl: 'public-read'
})
```

Then, I used the result to create an HTML form to upload a file.

The IAM user (whose credentials I was using) needed the `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission to do it. Without that permission, I got access denied.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=180012

Answer (score 2):

You're still putting an ACL on the object that isn't the default.

I was not able to find a citation in the documentation, but it stands to reason that "you can put an object in this bucket" is not the same permission (or level of trust) as "you can specify who gets to access an object in this bucket," whether you specify that now, by uploading the object with a canned ACL, or decide later, by modifying the object's ACL.

The ability to set the object to `public` most definitely represents a different level of privilege.